# How to get back hosts file after accidental deletion

Tags: networking

I made a mistake and accidentally deleted hosts file from my system and cannot figure out how to get back my hosts (/etc/) file, when i do

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

it's showing sudo: unable to resolve host SystemName.

I am using ubunt 14.04 Lts Please help me out, i am just beginner.

I tried by sudo vi hosts and put

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0         ip6-localnet
ff00::0         ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
```

but no avail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the contents of my `/etc/hosts`. Obviously, change the second line to reflect your hostname.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   sparhawk-XPS-17

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: @Atiq No worries. If this solved your problem, please click the tick button on the left. Cheers.